# Почему в java ,если разделить init=5; на 2.0; будет 2.5

Tags: java, c++

Почему в java, если разделить `init=5;` на `2.0` будет `2.5`, разве число не должно округлятся до целого числа как в C++?

Comment: Замечу, что если в C++ вы разделите `5` на `2.0` (не на `2`), то тоже получите `2.5`...

Answer (score 5):

это происходит из-за того что вы добавили `.0` к `2`, и число стало не `int` а `float`, а при деление целого числа на дробное  получается также дробное

пример на c++

```
std::cout << 5 / 2 << std::endl;
std::cout << 5 / 2.0 << std::endl;
```

вывод:

> ```
> 2
> 2.5
> ```

в первом случае целое число делится на целое, а во втором целое на дробное